# Add-in and Formatting code using Code Automation Model

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, automation, add-in

im doing some ads-in for visual studio 2010 using code automation model i was able to insert some text to the editor , problem is after i insert code and all goes well i cant format the code , like you know when you press ctrl+K then ctrl+D to format your code ? i want something like that but from code ,

so lets say i have

the ProjectItem :

```
ProjectItem pi
```

i was hoping for something like :

```
pi.Document.Format();
```

so is it possible to format the document before i save it cause i realy dont want to have it saved unformatted....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it:

```
pi.Document.DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.FormatDocument");
```